Trying to get subregion from coordinates using countryinfo
very new to... everything. i am trying to use geometry to find subregions using latlng in getcountry. maybe the points/coordinates/geometry are not in the same format as latlng?
# getting data
df = pd.read_csv("earthquakes.csv")

# creating coordinates (POINTS)
df_geometry = [Point(xy) for xy in zip(df.longitude, df.latitude)]
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df, geometry = df_geometry)
gdf.head()

# setting sns default theme
sns.set_theme()

# defining subregion
def subregion(value):
    for _, country_info in CountryInfo().all().items():
        if country_info.__contains__("latlng") and country_info.__getitem__("latlng") == value: 
            return country_info.__getitem__("subregion")

# adding the subregion to gdf 
gdf["subregion"] = gdf["geometry"].apply(subregion)

# creating a scatter graph of longitude / magnitude
# colour coded to show continent
sns.jointplot(data=gdf, x="latitude", y="mag", hue="subregion")


Start by defining the coordinate system when you create the geodataframe gpd.GeoDataFrame(df, geometry = df_geometry) should be gpd.GeoDataFrame(df, geometry = df_geometry, crs=4326) or whatever coordinate system your coordinates are in

As you are already using Geopandas, you could use some spatial dataset with subregion attribute and sjoin() (spatial join) it to your locations.
With .latlng() you'd just get a single point somewhere in the country, I'm afraid it will not be too useful for matching your own locations to countries / subregions.
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd
import seaborn as sns

# Natural Earth 10m dataset, includes SUBREGION
# https://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/10m-cultural-vectors/
ne_gdf = gpd.read_file("https://naciscdn.org/naturalearth/10m/cultural/ne_10m_admin_0_countries.zip")

# csv feed, https://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/csv.php
df = pd.read_csv("https://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/summary/2.5_month.csv")

# create Geopandas frame, spatial join to add SUBREGION from ne_gdf
gdf = (
    gpd.GeoDataFrame(df, geometry=gpd.points_from_xy(df.longitude, df.latitude), crs="WGS84")
    .sjoin(ne_gdf.loc[:, ["SUBREGION", "geometry"]], how="left")
    # fill NA values (outside of coutry polygons) to plot those as well
    # .fillna({"SUBREGION" : "N/A"})
)

g = sns.jointplot(data=gdf, x="latitude", y="mag", hue="SUBREGION")
sns.move_legend(g.figure.axes[0],"upper left", bbox_to_anchor=(1.25, 1))


